# How should I store the first line that got from getline() in c?

Tags: c, posix, getline

```
int main(){
    char *input = NULL; 
    char *first = NULL;
    size_t len = 100;
    int count = 0;  
    while(getline(&input, &len, stdin)!= EOF){
        if(count == 0){
            first = input;
            printf("------>%s, count = %d\n", first, count);//test printer
        }
        else{
            printf("%d, %s, %s\n", count, input, first);//test printer
        }
        count++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I was trying to seperate two parts --the first line I input and rest of string after the first line...but I don't know why I can't store first line seperately successfully.

In order to stop assignning input to first(first line input), I used count to determine where should I stop which means if count is zero which means my input is first line. And then in the while loop, after the second line you input, you will print second line, first line...I set test printer on else statement, I found the first changed when I input the second line. Which means when jump to else statement, first is not printing what I want(actual first line) but the same line as input.

I am so confusing about this. Why the value changed? How should I store the first line value at a separately char array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you make `first` point to the same memory as `input`. Both variables are pointing to the same memory after the assignment `first = input`.

You need to *duplicate* the string instead, using e.g. `strdup`:

```
first = strdup(input);
```

---

Also note that you are using [the `getline` function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) wrong. From [the manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html):

> If `*lineptr` is set to NULL **and `*n` is set 0** before the call, then `getline()` will allocate a buffer for storing the line

For the `getline` function to allocate memory you need to set`len` to zero too. *Or* allocate memory yourself. If `*n` is *not* zero the above text implies that the `getline` call does not allocate memory, but uses the pointer `*lineptr` as it was valid and pointing to allocated memory of at least `*n` bytes. You have a null-pointer, which will lead to *undefined behavior as `getline` uses that pointer and writes to the memory it points to.

And remember that if you ask `getline` to allocate memory for you, and you use `strdup`, then you need to `free` that memory.

Lastly, `getline` can modify the length so you need to reset it before every call.